# findviewbyid gives unexpected nullpointer exception

Tags: java, android

I have just created simple app and added button.

```
MyActivity.java

package com.example.myapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
    Button buttonClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
}
```

and here is xml file

```
Main.xml

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Hello World, MyActivity"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
        <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="New Button"
                android:id="@+id/button" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Androidmanifest is same as created by ide

so when i try to run this code i recive nullpointer exception caused by `findviewbyid` what am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your `Button buttonClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);` inside `onCreate`. Eg:

```
Button buttonClick;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    buttonClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
}
```

Comment: To help the poster understand why that is: the button only exists in the layout for that activity after `setContentView` is called in `onCreate`, and putting it outside that function means the layout hasn't been created yet when you're trying to assign the button. `findViewById` returns null if the view was not found in the layout it's called on, so trying to use it will give you a NullPointerException.

Comment: That's great and valuable explanation @ipavl